# Why can't I upload files >1MB using multer-s3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, multer-s3

is there a reason why multer won't let me upload files greater than 1MB?

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import multer from 'multer';
import multerS3 from "multer-s3"
import s3 from "../config/amazons3"



const uploadController = { 

    transferFile: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const s3upload = multer({
                storage: multerS3({
                    s3: s3,
                    acl: 'public-read',
                    bucket: 'filetransferawsbucket1',
                    metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
                        cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname})
                    },
                    key: (req, file, cb) => {
                        try {
                            console.log("File", file)
                            const key: string = `medium_zip_file_${uuidv4()}`
                            cb(null, key)
                        } catch (error) {
                            cb(error) // Pass the error to multer
                        }
                    }
                }),
                limits: {
                    fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, // 5 GB limit
                    fieldSize: 52428800
                },
                fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
                    if (file.mimetype === 'application/zip') {
                      // Allow only zip files
                      cb(null, true)
                    } else {
                      cb(new Error('Invalid file type. Only zip files are allowed.'))
                    }
                },
            })

            console.log('Before Multer Middleware')

            s3upload.single('file')(req, res, (err) => {
                console.log('After Multer Middleware')
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Multer error:', err)
                    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Error processing file upload" })
                }
            })

         

            res.status(201).send("Success")

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("TRANSFER FILE ERROR", error)
            res.status(500).json({ error: "Error transferring file" })
        }
    }
    
}
```

If I run it with files <1MB they are successfully uploaded to my aws s3 bucket. But when I attempt uploading files >1MB it doesn't run this block of code. ( s3upload.single('file') works but the bit after doesn't )

```
            s3upload.single('file')(req, res, (err) => {
                console.log('After Multer Middleware')
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Multer error:', err)
                    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Error processing file upload" })
                }
            })
```

It doesn't give an error message or anything (I get a response of 201 success). I've tried adjusting the CORS settings and the bucket policy but that's not worked.

When I upload a 1.2MB file using aws cli it works. Just can't seem to get it to work with node js using multer-s3

**UPDATE:**

I have moved some functions around and it seems to be working now. This is the updated code:

**uploadRouter.ts**

```
import express from "express"
import uploadController, { s3upload } from "../controllers/uploadContoller"


const router = express.Router()

router.post("/transferFile", s3upload.single("file"), uploadController.transferFile)


export default router
```

**uploadController.ts** (original file with uploadS3 moved into uploadRouter.ts)

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { TransferModel } from "../models/transferModel";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import multer from 'multer';
import multerS3 from "multer-s3"
import s3 from "../config/amazons3"


interface IUploadContoller {
    transferFile: (req: Request, res: Response) => Promise<void>
    transferFileBusBoy?: (req: Request, res: Response) => Promise<void>
}

export const s3upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        acl: 'public-read',
        bucket: 'filetransferawsbucket1',
        metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname})
        },
        key: (req, file, cb) => {
            try {
                console.log("***FILE***", file)
                const key: string = `medium_zip_file_${uuidv4()}` // replace this with uuid -> https://filetransferawsbucket1.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/{uuid}
                cb(null, key)
            } catch (error) {
                cb(error) // Pass the error to multer
            }
        }
    }),
    limits: {
        fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, // 5 GB limit
        fieldSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, 
    },
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.mimetype === 'application/zip') {
          // Allow only zip files
          cb(null, true)
        } else {
          cb(new Error('Invalid file type. Only zip files are allowed.'))
        }
    },
})


const uploadController: IUploadContoller = { 

    transferFile: async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        try {
            console.log('Before Multer Middleware')
        
            res.status(201).send("Success")

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("TRANSFER FILE ERROR", error)
            res.status(500).json({ error: "Error transferring file" })
        }
    },

    
}

export default uploadController
```

My guess is when I moved the s3upload.single("file") middleware directly into the route definition, it could have ensured that the file was processed and uploaded to S3 before proceeding with the rest of the route logic(?)

As a side note: it's also working for files of ~1GB but its taking quite long (up to 5 mins) - any suggestions on how to speed it up would be welcome

Comment: plz increase file size upload concept from server .ini fille

Comment: upload_max_filesize in php.ini

Comment: I'm using node js so I don't think I'd have access to any sort of php.ini file or upload_max_filesize parameter

Comment: Are you by any chance using nginx?

Comment: I'm not using nginx

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes people say they are not using nginx then remember they are using an nginx or apache reverse proxy.

Comment: I've come across this solution for nginx to increase the file size limit

http {
    # ...
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    # ...
}

but I haven't installed nginx for this project so I doubt this would be of any use? aws cli is working as expected so I think its a node/express/multer-s3 issue

Comment: I agree. You have set the limits property within the options object so when multer creates a new instance of multer it will assign `this.limits = options.limits`. I suspect something else is limiting the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My guess is when I moved the s3upload.single("file") middleware directly into the route definition, it could have ensured that the file was processed and uploaded to S3 before proceeding with the rest of the route logic(?)

I'm not sure how your middlewares were set up before the rewrite, but you are mixing async, sync and callbacks, all within a single function.

Your controller method is async, but your code that is uploading S3 is calling these two methods:

```
s3upload.single('file')(req, res, (err) => {
  console.log('After Multer Middleware')
  if (err) {
    console.log('Multer error:', err)
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Error processing file upload" })
  }
});

res.status(201).send("Success");
```

and returns right away, without so much as an await.

Since you only have one shot at setting a response status in ExpressJS, this function will only ever send a 201 Success.

Technically, the closed response should not affect callbacks, but since `multer` is a middleware as well, it might be smart and not bother to call the callbacks if it sees that the request is closed.

If you are using the async pattern, make sure to wrap your controllers in `express-async-handler` and actually await for the results of your uploads and other asynchronous operations.

If you want to use callbacks or middlewares, make sure to stack them in the right way (it looks like you did that already), or move your processing logiс inside the callbacks:

```
s3upload
  .single('file')(req, res,
     (err) => err
       ? req.status(500).send("Error")
       : req.status(201).send("Success")))
```

, so that the 201 only gets sent after the upload has completed.